# jQuery: If element is empty excluding whitespace and comments

Tags: javascript, jquery

The following code checks if an element has no content within it(not including whitespace or line breaks). In addition to it ignoring whitespace, I would also like it to ignore comments or anything that isn't an HTML tag if possible. How can I achieve this?

```
        if( $.trim( $("#element").html() ) == '' ) {
            // do something if empty
        }
```

Answer (score 7):

Based on your comment:

> *I want to check if the element contains any nodes, but not comments and whitespace.*

To determine if an element contains nodes excluding comments, use [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/).

To determine if an element contains text content excluding whitespace, use [$.trim()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.trim/) with [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/).

Combining these, your code becomes:

```
if($('#element').children().length>0 && $.trim($("#element").text())!=='')
```

Because non-zero numbers are [truthy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/) and empty strings are [falsy](http://www.sitepoint.com/javascript-truthy-falsy/), this can be shortened to:

```
if($('#element').children().length && !$.trim($("#element").text()))
```

In the example below, `element2` is the only element that matches the criteria (non-comment nodes with whitespace only):

```js
function test(el) {
  if($(el).children().length &&  !$.trim($(el).text())) {
    return 'Success - children with no visible text';
  }
  else {
    return 'Failure - '+
           $(el).children().length+' children -'+
           $(el).text();
  }
}

$('body').append('<p>element1: '+test('#element1')+'</p>');

$('body').append('<p>element2: '+test('#element2')+'</p>');

$('body').append('<p>element3: '+test('#element3')+'</p>');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element1">
  Lorem ipsum
  <span>dolor</span>
  <!-- nothing to see here -->
  <strong>sit <em>amet</em></strong>
</div>

<div id="element2">
  <span> </span>
  <!-- nothing to see here -->
  <strong> <em> </em></strong>
</div>

<div id="element3">
  <!-- nothing to see here -->
</div>
<hr>
```

It may be informative to see how [.children()](http://api.jquery.com/children/) differs from [.contents()](http://api.jquery.com/contents/), which *does* include comment nodes as well as text nodes:

```js
constants='|element|attribute|text|cdata section|entity reference|entity|processing instruction|comment|document|document type|document fragment|notation'.split('|');

$('#info').children().each(function() {
  var t= $(this)[0];
  $('#children').append(
    '<tr><td>'+(t.tagName || '')+
        '<td>'+constants[t.nodeType]+
        '<td>'+(t.textContent.trim() || '<em>whitespace</em>')
  );
})

$('#info').contents().each(function() {
  var t= $(this)[0];
  $('#contents').append(
    '<tr><td>'+(t.tagName || '')+
        '<td>'+constants[t.nodeType]+
        '<td>'+(t.textContent.trim() || '<em>whitespace</em>')
  );
})
```

```css
body, table {
  font: 12px verdana;
}

table {
  border: 1px solid #666;
  border-collapse: collapse;
}

td, th {
  border-right: 1px solid #ddd;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #bbb;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="info">
  Lorem ipsum
  <span>dolor</span>
  <!-- nothing to see here -->
  <strong>sit <em>amet</em></strong>
</div>
<hr>
<strong>.children():</strong>
<table id="children">
  <tr><th>Tag<th>Node type<th>Text content
</table>
<hr>
<strong>.contents():</strong>
<table id="contents">
  <tr><th>Tag<th>Node type<th>Text content
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `textContent` property of the element.

The `textContent` property sets or returns the textual content of the specified node, **and all its descendants**. Comments, however, are not counted since it's not HTML tag.

See the sample code:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  alert("DIV1: " + $.trim( $("#div1").text()) );
  alert("DIV2:" + $.trim( $("#div2").text()) );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="div1"> <!-- this div contains a comment --> </div>
<div id="div2">This div has <b>SOMETHING</b> inside</div>
```

Comment: jQuery's `text()` function uses textContent for element nodes.  So `$.trim( $("#div1").get(0).textContent)` is equivalent to `$.trim( $("#div1").text()`.

Comment: @RickHitchcock Yes, it's the same, but looks better :)

Comment: Won't this only check if the element contains text? I want to check if the element contains any nodes, but not comments and whitespace.

Comment: Well, let me explain it in the most simple way: this code checks VISIBLE TEXT inside the entire element. Including the texts inside all the element's children. Excluding white spaces. Excluding comments. Excluding images.